# Boundary of hatching in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I am trying to plot 4 kinds of hatch which correspond to different values in an array. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

a = np.array([[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
              [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
              [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],[3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]])

plt.contourf(a, hatches=[None, '\\\\', '///', '*'], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

I got this result

[image]

The boundry contains many narrow bands. But I only want to plot 4 rectangular hatching. How should I remove these bands?

Comment: This is a contour plot. The contour plot cannot know that you do not want to interpolate if the main purpose of a contour plot is to interpolate to find the contours? Is this a small example for a bigger use case or do you actually want to produce 4 hatched shapes?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  This is only a small example. I am trying to add hatching onto an image which contists of many patches. Each patch has a specific value, there are 4 values:0, 1, 2, 3. I'm not so familiar with contourf, I only found one example of contourf hatching on the website of matplotlib but it's not like this.

Comment: In that case I currently have no idea, apart from drawing each patch individually and adding the respective hatch style to it, which is probably undesired here. I might think of it more later on.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you have any idea, please let me know. Thank you so much.